# Evaluate integral with gaussian curvature

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, curvature

[image]

I thought evaluating it in the following way: $$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}K(x,y)\sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} \, dy\,dx &= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \sqrt{\det L_{ij}}\cdot \sqrt{{\frac{\det L_{ij}}{\det{g_{ij}}}}} \, dy\,dx\\
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \sqrt{\det{L_{ij}}}\cdot \sqrt{\det (g^{ij}L_{ij})} \,dy\,dx \\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\sqrt{\det L_{ij}}\cdot \sqrt {\det{L^i_{\space\space j}}} \, dy\, dx
\end{align}$$

but from here I'm stuck. How can I continue evaluating the integral above?

Comment: What is $L_{ij}$?

Comment: @Vlad it's the second fundamental form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\renewcommand \t\theta
\renewcommand \f\phi
\renewcommand \p\phi
\renewcommand {\d}{\partial\,}
\newcommand \T \Theta
\newcommand \P \Phi
\newcommand \F \Phi
$
**HINT**: Recall that Gaussian curvature of a surface is equal to Jacobian determinant of the Gauss map for this surface.

---

One can compute integral $ 
\int_0^{2\pi}\!\int_0^{\pi}K(x,y)\sqrt{\left\vert g_{ij}\right\vert} \, dy\,dx  $ on surface $M$ by mapping $M$ to the unit sphere $S^2$, i.e. by making change of variables defined by a Gauss map $G$.

$$
\big(\, \t, \f\, \big) = G\big(\, x, y \, \big)
\iff
\begin{cases}
\t = \T(x,y) \\
\f = \P(x,y),
\end{cases} 
\quad 
\big(\, x, y \, \big) = G^{-1}\big(\, \t , \p \, \big)
\iff
\begin{cases}
x = X(\t, \p) \\
\f = Y(\t, \p).
\end{cases} 
$$

Changing variables in the integral requires multiplying the integrand to Jacobian determinant $J_{G^{-1}}$ of the map $G^{-1}:S^2\to M$.

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}K(x,y)\sqrt{\left\vert g_{ij}\right\vert}\, dy\,dx  
= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}K J_{G}\sqrt{\left\vert g_{ij}\right\vert} \, d\t\,d\p,
$$

where $J_G$ is the determinant of Jacobian matrix for $G$:
$\quad 
J_G = 
\left\vert \dfrac{D \left(\, x , y \, \right)}{D\left(\, \t , \p \, \right)}\right\vert
=
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\d X}{\d \t} & \frac{\d X}{\d \p} \\
\frac{\d Y}{\d \t} & \frac{\d Y}{\d \p} 
\end{vmatrix} 
$

Since Jacobian of a map is reciprocal of Jacobian of the its inverse, 
$$
J_G = \left\vert\dfrac{D(x,y)}{D(\t,\p)}\right\vert 
= \left\vert\dfrac{D(\t,\p)}{D(x,y)}\right\vert^{-1} 
= \dfrac{1}{J_{G^{-1}}},
$$
and since Jacobian determinant of Gauss map is equal to Gaussian curvature, 
we get rid of $K(x,y)$ and compute the integral.

I think you can pick it up from here and make the final step by plugging everything into the integral and computing it.

---

To summarize, in order to compute this integral we use the following facts:

- [Integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) involves multiplying integral by Jacobian
- The Jacobian on an inverse transformation is reciprocal to the Jacobian of direct transformation
- Gaussian curvature is equal to the Jacobian of Gauss map

---

**PS** The integral you are computing looks a lot like *total Gaussian curvature*.